# How can I display custom directive within an ui-view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a configuration as in the following plunkr : http://plnkr.co/nya3cr

Of which I have states as :

```
.state('main.layout', {
        url : '/l',
        abstract : true,
        views : {
          'left' : {
            templateUrl : 'left.html',
            controller : 'LeftCtrl'
          },
          'right' : {
            templateUrl : 'right.html',
            controller : 'RightCtrl'
          },
          'middle' : {
            templateUrl : 'middle.html',
            controller : 'MiddleCtrl'
          },
          'bottom' : {
            templateUrl : 'bottom.html'
          }
        }
      })
```

I am trying to use custom directives in ui-views like this.

```
.directive('sidebarDirective', function () {
    return {
      template: 'Hello hello!',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.text('this is the sidebarDirective directive');
      }
    };
  });
```

But I cant use it within an ui-view element, such as in my configuration, I have tried keeping my custom directive (sidebar-directive) in left.html

```
<div sidebar-directive></div>
```

as well as in right.html but it doesn't show up. I may be missing some key understanding about how to include directives in ui-view states. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `A` instead of `E` for **`restrict`**. Check the updated [version here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nPgUWn?p=preview)

```
  .directive('sidebarDirective', function () {
    return {
      template: 'Hello hello!',
      restrict: 'A', // here should be A, could be even 'AE', but for us A is must!
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.text('this is the sidebarDirective directive');
      }
    };
  });
```

Because `A` means **attribute** and `E` means **element** and we are using it as attribute:

```
<div sidebar-directive></div>
```

Updated version is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nPgUWn?p=preview)

The [Developer guide - directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) *(small cite)*:

> The restrict option is typically set to:
>
> - 'A' - only matches attribute name
> - 'E' - only matches element name
> - 'C' - only matches class name
>
> These restrictions can all be combined as needed:
>
> - 'AEC' - matches either attribute or element or class name

Comment: Thank you very much! Suppose if I have to control the logic on when the directive is displayed, where should I write this logic?

Comment: I would put it this way: directive created by you, for your application - are for you. So it fully depends on your needs. There is no general rule. Context should decide. I'd say ;) Hope it helped a bit ;) Good luck with `UI-Router`, awesome tool...